# Launcher with Desktop Action question

Tags: gnome, .desktop

I have two desktop entry files, one is used to launch an application that runs in a terminal window, the other launches a GUI version of the same program.  I have added a `[Desktop Action <Action Name>]` to both that launches the same  GUI program (actually, Firefox opening a local html file containing the documentation for the app).  In the first instance the desktop file includes the line `Terminal=true`, in the second `Teminal=false`. Both launch their targets correctly and the Desktop Action launches Firefox as expected. However, in the second case just before Firefox starts up, a terminal window opens. When I close Firefox, after a very short pause the terminal closes too. If I close the terminal, Firefox also closes. Adding a `Terminal=false` line to the `[Desktop Action <Action Name>]` entry has no effect.  If Firefox is already running, the terminal opens and immediately closes without affecting the opening of a new tab displaying the appropriate local file.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Gnome 3.28.2 and all updates installed.

This is just a minor issue, but I'd like to understand what is going on. Is there a way to suppress the opening of the blank terminal?

Here is a link to the desktop configuration file
https://pastebin.com/tYxLcQnJ

Comment: This sounds like kinda expected behaviour with `Terminal=true`. Note that  the `[Desktop Action <Action Name>]` group doesn't support a separate `Terminal=false` key.

Comment: @RichardQuint Please post the malfunctioning desktop file.